# Php create file json

Tags: php, json, file

I need help in creating a json file.

My php code:

```
<?php

    $callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
    $ev = array('data'=>array('channel'=>array()));

    foreach ($this->categoriefigli as $figli):
        foreach ($this->articoli as $art):

            if($figli['categoriafigli_id'] === $art['categoriepadri']):

                $e[] = array('ids' => $art['id'],
                          'titolo' => $art['titolo'],
                     'descrizione' => $art['descrizione'],
                          'prezzo' => $art['prezzo_tavolo']);

                $a = array('id' => $figli['categoriafigli_id'],
                         'nome' => $figli['categoriafigli_nome'],
                        'items' => array());

                array_push($a['items'],$e);
            endif;

        endforeach;

        array_push($ev['data']['channel'],$a);

    endforeach;

    if ($callback) 
    {
        header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
        echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($ev) . ');';
    } 
    else 
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo Zend_Json::encode($ev);
    }
?>
```

The result is almost correct, the problem is that inserts the values ​​duplicating also in different categories

result json :

```
{"data":{"channel":[{"id":"4","nome":"Bevande","items":[[{"ids":"126","titolo":"Acqua       minerale (0,75)","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"127","titolo":"Birra alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"128","titolo":"Birra alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"129","titolo":"Spillatore da 3,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"33.00"},{"ids":"130","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"131","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"132","titolo":"Bibita in lattina","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"133","titolo":"Vino alla spina 1 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"134","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"5.00"},{"ids":"135","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,25 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"3.00"}]]},{"id":"14","nome":"Birre artigianali","items":[[{"ids":"126","titolo":"Acqua minerale (0,75)","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"127","titolo":"Birra alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"128","titolo":"Birra alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"129","titolo":"Spillatore da 3,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"33.00"},{"ids":"130","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"131","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"132","titolo":"Bibita in lattina","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"133","titolo":"Vino alla spina 1 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"134","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"5.00"},{"ids":"135","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,25 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"3.00"},{"ids":"196","titolo":"Birra Nera","descrizione":"","prezzo":"8.00"}]]},{"id":"17","nome":"Vini rosati","items":[[{"ids":"126","titolo":"Acqua minerale (0,75)","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"127","titolo":"Birra alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"128","titolo":"Birra alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"129","titolo":"Spillatore da 3,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"33.00"},{"ids":"130","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"131","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"132","titolo":"Bibita in lattina","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"133","titolo":"Vino alla spina 1 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"134","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"5.00"},{"ids":"135","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,25 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"3.00"},{"ids":"196","titolo":"Birra Nera","descrizione":"","prezzo":"8.00"},{"ids":"174","titolo":"Schiava Valdagine Doc","descrizione":"Concilio","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"175","titolo":"Rosato del Garda \"Rosamara\" Doc","descrizione":"Costaripa","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"176","titolo":"Lagrein Rose' Doc","descrizione":"Tramin","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"177","titolo":"Lacrima Rosa Doc","descrizione":"Mastroberardino","prezzo":"13.00"}]]},{"id":"18","nome":"Le bollicine","items":[[{"ids":"126","titolo":"Acqua minerale (0,75)","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"127","titolo":"Birra alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"128","titolo":"Birra alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"129","titolo":"Spillatore da 3,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"33.00"},{"ids":"130","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"131","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"132","titolo":"Bibita in lattina","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"133","titolo":"Vino alla spina 1 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"134","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"5.00"},{"ids":"135","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,25 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"3.00"},{"ids":"196","titolo":"Birra Nera","descrizione":"","prezzo":"8.00"},{"ids":"174","titolo":"Schiava Valdagine Doc","descrizione":"Concilio","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"175","titolo":"Rosato del Garda \"Rosamara\" Doc","descrizione":"Costaripa","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"176","titolo":"Lagrein Rose' Doc","descrizione":"Tramin","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"177","titolo":"Lacrima Rosa Doc","descrizione":"Mastroberardino","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"136","titolo":"Prosecco di Valdobbiadene Docg \"Giallo Oro\"","descrizione":"F.lli Ruggeri","prezzo":"11.00"},{"ids":"137","titolo":"Franciacorta Brut Docg \"Conte di Provaglio\"","descrizione":"Ziliani Chiara","prezzo":"19.00"},{"ids":"138","titolo":"Franciacorta Saten Docg \"Conte di Provaglio\"","descrizione":"Ziliani Chiara","prezzo":"19.00"},{"ids":"139","titolo":"Franciacorta Brut Docg","descrizione":"Contadi Castaldi","prezzo":"22.00"},{"ids":"140","titolo":"Franciacorta Rose' \"Brolese\" Docg","descrizione":"F.lli Muratori","prezzo":"22.00"},{"ids":"141","titolo":"Champagne Brut","descrizione":"Stephane Breton","prezzo":"41.00"},{"ids":"142","titolo":"Moscato d'Asti Docg","descrizione":"Cerutti Enrico","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"143","titolo":"Brachetto d'Acqui Docg \"Pineto\"","descrizione":"Marenco","prezzo":"14.00"}]]},{"id":"19","nome":"Vini rossi","items":[[{"ids":"126","titolo":"Acqua minerale (0,75)","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"127","titolo":"Birra alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"128","titolo":"Birra alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"129","titolo":"Spillatore da 3,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"33.00"},{"ids":"130","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"131","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"132","titolo":"Bibita in lattina","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"133","titolo":"Vino alla spina 1 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"134","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"5.00"},{"ids":"135","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,25 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"3.00"},{"ids":"196","titolo":"Birra Nera","descrizione":"","prezzo":"8.00"},{"ids":"174","titolo":"Schiava Valdagine Doc","descrizione":"Concilio","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"175","titolo":"Rosato del Garda \"Rosamara\" Doc","descrizione":"Costaripa","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"176","titolo":"Lagrein Rose' Doc","descrizione":"Tramin","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"177","titolo":"Lacrima Rosa Doc","descrizione":"Mastroberardino","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"136","titolo":"Prosecco di Valdobbiadene Docg \"Giallo Oro\"","descrizione":"F.lli Ruggeri","prezzo":"11.00"},{"ids":"137","titolo":"Franciacorta Brut Docg \"Conte di Provaglio\"","descrizione":"Ziliani Chiara","prezzo":"19.00"},{"ids":"138","titolo":"Franciacorta Saten Docg \"Conte di Provaglio\"","descrizione":"Ziliani Chiara","prezzo":"19.00"},{"ids":"139","titolo":"Franciacorta Brut Docg","descrizione":"Contadi Castaldi","prezzo":"22.00"},{"ids":"140","titolo":"Franciacorta Rose' \"Brolese\" Docg","descrizione":"F.lli Muratori","prezzo":"22.00"},{"ids":"141","titolo":"Champagne Brut","descrizione":"Stephane Breton","prezzo":"41.00"},{"ids":"142","titolo":"Moscato d'Asti Docg","descrizione":"Cerutti Enrico","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"143","titolo":"Brachetto d'Acqui Docg \"Pineto\"","descrizione":"Marenco","prezzo":"14.00"},{"ids":"159","titolo":"Dolcetto d'Alba Doc cl.375","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Colline S.Ponzio","prezzo":"6.00"},{"ids":"160","titolo":"Dolcetto Diano d'Alba Doc \"Sori' Richin\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Casavecchia","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"161","titolo":"Dolcetto Dogliani Doc \"Sori' But\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Abbona Annamaria","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"162","titolo":"Dolcetto d'Alba Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Scuola Enologica","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"163","titolo":"Dolcetto d'Alba Doc \"Mosesco\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Prunotto","prezzo":"14.00"},{"ids":"164","titolo":"Barbera d'Alba Doc \"Diletta\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Cascina Pellerino","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"165","titolo":"Barbera d'Asti Superiore Doc \"Cascina Fonda\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Guasti Clemente","prezzo":"17.00"},{"ids":"166","titolo":"Barbera del Monferrato Doc \"Clementina\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Guasti Clemente","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"167","titolo":"Ruche' di Castagnole Monferrato Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Cantine Sant'Agata","prezzo":"14.00"},{"ids":"168","titolo":"Nebbiolo d'Alba Doc ","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Pelassa Mario","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"169","titolo":"Barbaresco 2007 Docg ","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Produttori del Barbaresco","prezzo":"26.00"},{"ids":"170","titolo":"Barolo \"Tortoniano\" Docg","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Michele Chiarlo","prezzo":"29.00"},{"ids":"171","titolo":"Chianti \"Castiglioni\" Docg","descrizione":"Origine: Toscana Marchesi De' Frescobaldi","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"172","titolo":"Toscana Rosso \"Pater\" Igt","descrizione":"Origine: Toscana Marchesi De' Frescobaldi","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"173","titolo":"Montepulciano d'Abruzzo Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Abruzzo Masciarelli","prezzo":"13.00"}]]},{"id":"20","nome":"Vini bianchi","items":[[{"ids":"126","titolo":"Acqua minerale (0,75)","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"127","titolo":"Birra alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"128","titolo":"Birra alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"129","titolo":"Spillatore da 3,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"33.00"},{"ids":"130","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina piccola","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.50"},{"ids":"131","titolo":"Coca cola alla spina media","descrizione":"","prezzo":"4.50"},{"ids":"132","titolo":"Bibita in lattina","descrizione":"","prezzo":"2.00"},{"ids":"133","titolo":"Vino alla spina 1 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"134","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,5 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"5.00"},{"ids":"135","titolo":"Vino alla spina 0,25 Lt","descrizione":"","prezzo":"3.00"},{"ids":"196","titolo":"Birra Nera","descrizione":"","prezzo":"8.00"},{"ids":"174","titolo":"Schiava Valdagine Doc","descrizione":"Concilio","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"175","titolo":"Rosato del Garda \"Rosamara\" Doc","descrizione":"Costaripa","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"176","titolo":"Lagrein Rose' Doc","descrizione":"Tramin","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"177","titolo":"Lacrima Rosa Doc","descrizione":"Mastroberardino","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"136","titolo":"Prosecco di Valdobbiadene Docg \"Giallo Oro\"","descrizione":"F.lli Ruggeri","prezzo":"11.00"},{"ids":"137","titolo":"Franciacorta Brut Docg \"Conte di Provaglio\"","descrizione":"Ziliani Chiara","prezzo":"19.00"},{"ids":"138","titolo":"Franciacorta Saten Docg \"Conte di Provaglio\"","descrizione":"Ziliani Chiara","prezzo":"19.00"},{"ids":"139","titolo":"Franciacorta Brut Docg","descrizione":"Contadi Castaldi","prezzo":"22.00"},{"ids":"140","titolo":"Franciacorta Rose' \"Brolese\" Docg","descrizione":"F.lli Muratori","prezzo":"22.00"},{"ids":"141","titolo":"Champagne Brut","descrizione":"Stephane Breton","prezzo":"41.00"},{"ids":"142","titolo":"Moscato d'Asti Docg","descrizione":"Cerutti Enrico","prezzo":"10.00"},{"ids":"143","titolo":"Brachetto d'Acqui Docg \"Pineto\"","descrizione":"Marenco","prezzo":"14.00"},{"ids":"159","titolo":"Dolcetto d'Alba Doc cl.375","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Colline S.Ponzio","prezzo":"6.00"},{"ids":"160","titolo":"Dolcetto Diano d'Alba Doc \"Sori' Richin\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Casavecchia","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"161","titolo":"Dolcetto Dogliani Doc \"Sori' But\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Abbona Annamaria","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"162","titolo":"Dolcetto d'Alba Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Scuola Enologica","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"163","titolo":"Dolcetto d'Alba Doc \"Mosesco\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Prunotto","prezzo":"14.00"},{"ids":"164","titolo":"Barbera d'Alba Doc \"Diletta\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Cascina Pellerino","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"165","titolo":"Barbera d'Asti Superiore Doc \"Cascina Fonda\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Guasti Clemente","prezzo":"17.00"},{"ids":"166","titolo":"Barbera del Monferrato Doc \"Clementina\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Guasti Clemente","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"167","titolo":"Ruche' di Castagnole Monferrato Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Cantine Sant'Agata","prezzo":"14.00"},{"ids":"168","titolo":"Nebbiolo d'Alba Doc ","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Pelassa Mario","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"169","titolo":"Barbaresco 2007 Docg ","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Produttori del Barbaresco","prezzo":"26.00"},{"ids":"170","titolo":"Barolo \"Tortoniano\" Docg","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Michele Chiarlo","prezzo":"29.00"},{"ids":"171","titolo":"Chianti \"Castiglioni\" Docg","descrizione":"Origine: Toscana Marchesi De' Frescobaldi","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"172","titolo":"Toscana Rosso \"Pater\" Igt","descrizione":"Origine: Toscana Marchesi De' Frescobaldi","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"173","titolo":"Montepulciano d'Abruzzo Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Abruzzo Masciarelli","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"144","titolo":"Langhe Arneis Doc cl.375","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte\r\nColline S. Ponzio","prezzo":"8.00"},{"ids":"145","titolo":"Roero Arneis Docg","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte\r\nOlivero Pietro","prezzo":"11.00"},{"ids":"146","titolo":"Roero Arnei Docg ","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Matteo Coreggia","prezzo":"16.00"},{"ids":"147","titolo":"Langhe Favorita Doc \"la Vignassa\"","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Cravanzola Fabrizio","prezzo":"9.00"},{"ids":"148","titolo":"Erbaluce di Caluso Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Piemonte Tenuta Roletto","prezzo":"11.00"},{"ids":"149","titolo":"Riviera Ligure di Ponente Pigato Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Liguria Le Mimose","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"150","titolo":"Riviera Ligure di Ponente Vermentino Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Liguria Le Mimose","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"151","titolo":"Gewurztraminer A.A. Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Alto Adige Girlan","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"152","titolo":"Muller Thurgau A.A. Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Alto Adige Elena Walch","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"153","titolo":"Tocai Friulano Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Friuli Venezia Giulia Produttori di Cormons","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"154","titolo":"Verdicchio dei Castelli di Jesi Doc","descrizione":"Origine: Marche Moncaro","prezzo":"12.00"},{"ids":"155","titolo":"Greco di Tufo Docg","descrizione":"Origine: Campania Mastrobernardino","prezzo":"16.00"},{"ids":"156","titolo":"Fiano di Avellino Docg","descrizione":"Origine: Campania Mastrobernardino","prezzo":"18.00"},{"ids":"157","titolo":"Sicilia Bianco Piano Maltese (Grillo-Catarratto)","descrizione":"Origine: Sicilia Tenute Rapitala'","prezzo":"13.00"},{"ids":"158","titolo":"Sicilia Bianco Calanica (Insolia-Chardonnay","descrizione":"Origine: Sicilia Duca di Salaparuta","prezzo":"12.00"}]]}]}}
```

Comment: the problem is not in your json but in the data coming from the DB. Can you please post your query?

Comment: Maybe print_r your array to confirm and see where the problem is.

Comment: You are using `$this->`... outside of an object...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're doing this

```
$e[] = array(
  'ids' => $art['id'],
  'titolo' => $art['titolo'],
  'descrizione' => $art['descrizione'], 
  'prezzo' => $art['prezzo_tavolo']
  );
```

Inside both of your foreach loops and never clearing it.

If each category has different products, you need to reset `$e` between categories, maybe like this:

```
foreach ($this->categoriefigli as $figli): 
  $e = array();
  foreach ($this->articoli as $art):
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the help.
Igy thanks for the solution..enough so little XD